# Toolbox can't find components when selecting an assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

When using VS2012 there seems to be an issue when trying to add an assembly to the toolbox that is located in a path where a folder has the '#' character in it. (Haven't tested for other characters)

**Test case 1:**
Browsing an assembly located at **C:\test#\An Assembly.dll**
Generates the error: There are no components in 'C:\test#\An Assembly.dll' that can be placed on the toolbox.

**Test case 2:**
Browsing an assembly located at **C:\test\An Assembly.dll**
No error appears, controls that are contained within the assembly are added to the list.

I don't remember this happening before as its been quite a few years that I changed my folder structure so I wonder if this is something that appeared with the Visual Studio 2012 Update 2.

Is there an inside why this started happening and is there a workaround that could allow '#' characters to be included in the path where an assembly is ?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You could file an issue with Microsoft Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio.

Comment: That is the plan as soon as I can verify that people with VS2012 and the update 2 suffer from the same issue and this isn't actually something by design.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and almost were desperated. But then I stumbled upon this post. At the end it seems even worse then mentioned  because it is not enough to put your resulting assembly into a different location without the "#". You have to ***store and compile*** your whole solution in a path without the "#". \
My problem was that all my C# Projects were located in a path with "somedirectory\C#\Projectname.....". Compiling and referencing the resulting assembly was working fine but when I tried to add components from the assembly to my Toolbox the upper mentioned error message arose. After reading this post here I first tried to copy my resulting DLL into a different path after compiling but that didn't change anything. After giving another try I changed the whole project path to get rid of the "#" and this was the trick to get it working!

Comment: Sadly the components I was testing were third party controls that didn't come with their source code. So recompiling them is not possible. I am sad to say that the new Visual Studio 2013 suffers from this issue as well.

Comment: For the protocol: I have spent TWO DAYS trying to install WebView2 component to Visual Studio 2022. The problem was, that my project folder is D:\source\C#\project... I changed the C# to "cSharp" and problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
I found stolenbike's answer to be helpful. I had my project in a folder named 'C#'. Renaming that folder and recompiling corrected the problem for me.
I am sure that this particular solution will help only a small subset of those receiving this error but corroboration is always helpful when tracing problems.