# Can't load a CustomUserControl DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, user-controls

I am a little bit lost. I created a Classlibary with some UserControls in it. The UserControl is named "UserControl1.cs" and the Project is called "UserControlsLibary".

This is my Projectstructure:

[image: Project Structure]

This is my "UserControl1.cs":

[image: UserControl1.cs]

I only added the Label. No other code in here.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserControlsLibary {
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {
        public UserControl1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I build the project. Then go to my other project, where I want to use my Control. Go to the Toolbox and select Choose Item -> Browse -> Select my dll in the Debug Folder and then the following Error occurs.

[image: ErrorMessage]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. A folder in my path was named "C#". After I named it CSharp and build the Solution it works.

I find this here.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311125/toolbox-cant-find-components-when-selecting-an-assembly)